# How to add forward slash automatically in keyup function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some field in which when the user types after 2nd alphabet, I need to add forward slash automatically.
Is this possible in jquery?

```
<input type="text" class="someclass"/>

    $(document).on('keyup','.classname', function(){
      var count = $(this).val();
    if(count == 2)
    {
      // Need stuff here
    }

});
```

Comment: Use `$(this).val().length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(document).on('keyup','.someclass', function(){
    var count = $(this).val().length;
    if(count == 2 && e.keyCode != 8){
      $(this).focus().val(function( index, value ) { return value + "/ " ;   });
    }
});
```

Comment: @UIDeveloper: FYI, this will mess up the user's insertion point. Maintaining the position of the insertion point is non-trivial and bound to break on at least some browsers. It involves hacks to make it work cross-browser. Look for "set position of cursor in input field" to find out how.

Comment: I m using this for mobile app bro

Comment: @Milind Anantwar: but when I delete it, it deletes upto 3rd character I mean the slash...after it is not deleted

Comment: change the condition `if(count == 2){` to `if(count == 2 && e.keyCode != 8){`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.someclass', function(e) {
  var count = $(this).val().length;
  if (count == 2) {
     $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="someclass" />
```